# Python encoding - error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

In my snippet below, I'm process a string of text thats: Déclaration.png

I return the description as unicode:

```
return self.render_json(request, {..."description": u''.join((instance.description)),..})
```

In another function, I use the description above as follows:

```
if document.description:
    file_name = document.description.split(".")
    file_name = "{}.{}.{}".format(
        "_".join(file_name[:-1]),
        str(document.id),
        file_name[-1]
    )
```

file_name is: `[u'De\u0301claration', u'png']`

When I try .format() on file_name I get the following error:

```
error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u0301' in position 2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you want the output to look like

Comment: I want something like 'De\u0301claration.123456.png'

Answer (score 0):

"{}.{}.{}" is a string but you try to fill it with unicode.

use

```
...
file_name = u"{}.{}.{}".format(
...
```

instead

also have a look at this nice talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Comment: I was just about to update my question saying that I did try that and got the same error. However, when I do that in a regular python shell, it all works. Thanks, i'll take a look at the talk

Comment: Maybe you have to restart the server